# Regular expression to restrict URL in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, regex

I had successfully restricted an URL in my web app to certain trusted IP, using below-mentioned config in haproxy config

```
acl trusted-ip src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst    
acl protected-page url /abc /abc/    
acl allowed-page url /abc/api/
http-request deny if protected-page !allowed-page !trusted-ip
```

I want all users to access "/abc/api" URL, while "/abc" will be accessible only to Trusted IP.
The problem here is if anyone from non-trusted IP enters "/abc?something" the URL "/abc" opens, in order to avoid this, I modified the config to

```
acl trusted-ip src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst
acl protected-page url_reg ^(?!\/abc\/api).*$
http-request deny if protected-page !trusted-ip
```

Now I was able to solve the above-mentioned problem, but the "/abc/api" is not accessible to anyone. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path` instead of `url`

> This extracts the request's URL path, which starts at the first slash
>   and
>       ends before the question mark (without the host part). A typical use is with
>       prefetch-capable caches, and with portals which need to aggregate multiple
>       information from databases and keep them in caches. Note that with outgoing
>       caches, it would be wiser to use "url" instead. With ACLs, it's typically
>       used to match exact file names (eg: "/login.php"), or directory parts using
>       the derivative forms. See also the "url" and "base" fetch methods.
>
> ```
> ACL derivatives :
>   path     : exact string match
>   path_beg : prefix match
>   path_dir : subdir match
>   path_dom : domain match
>   path_end : suffix match
>   path_len : length match
>   path_reg : regex match
>   path_sub : substring match
> ```

Comment: yes, got it working! used path_beg